# Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Tarifa could not be converted to string

Tags: forms, symfony

I saw a lot of similar issues, but I can't find the solution to this without adding __toString() method.

This works for me:

```
    $tarifa = new Tarifa();

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TarifaType', $tarifa);
```

And this does not work...

```
    $tarifa = new Tarifa();

    $peso1 = new TarifaPeso();
    $tarifa->addPeso($peso1);

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TarifaType', $tarifa);
```

Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this

```
$tarifa->addPeso($peso1->getPeso());
```

or this

```
$tarifa->addPeso($peso1->getAmount());
```

Depending on which property in TarifaPeso you have for this, if its also an entity and have getters

or its a ValueObject?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is correct because $peso1 is an instance of TarifaPeso and addPeso needs that type. Please, if you think in other causes please tell me... I need to solve this for my project

Answer (score 0):

Configure option `choice_label` to be a property from TarifaPeso in your  TarifaType class. This way, symfony does not intend to convert entity to  a string when printing the option label. Instead, it will take the property that you point to.

Comment: Sorry, it is not for a choice option, it is for an embed form. I have this in the TarifaType: 

            ->add('pesos', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => TarifaPesoType::class,
            ))

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it! The fact is I had added the field in the TarifaType that is related to the Collection. I removed the field below and now it works! Hope it could help anybody... Thanks to all

```
->add('tarifa', null, array(
                'attr' => array('autofocus' => true),
                'label' => 'label.code',
            ))
```